# Type of regression

Tags: regression, econometrics, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

I'm studying labor economics this year, although I'm from sociology. I would like to know if you guys could answer my doubt about a regression. In this study, the author says that will use variations of this regression, and then he says he will include "industry fixed effect". The question is: what is this model? linear regression? if so I can put fixed effects in linear regression? or it is panel data with fixed effects?[image]

Comment: Welcoe to CV waka. You should know that the terms "fixed effects" and "random effects" have somewhat muddled & contested meanings. There is *probably* less muddle and contestation within their use in econometrics, but heads up that if you receive conflicting answers from different sources that both may be "correct."